# ag-grid: Max columns supported in Multi column sorting

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid-community v19.1.4 with AngularJS1.x and I'm planning to use the multi-column sorting feature.
I would like to know if there is a maximum number of columns that can be sorted supported by ag-grid or if there is a recommended maximum?
I have checked the official ag-grid documentation
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/

But, it does not mention of any limits.

Comment: If you find the question can be improved, suggestions are welcome. Simply downvoting a question someone cares about does not make you cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to sort by multiple columns. The default action for multiple column sorting is for the user to hold down shift while clicking the column header.

The property `multiSortKey='ctrl'` is set so multiple column selection is achieved by holding down Control and selecting multiple columns.

However AG-Grid has not mentioned the limits on the multiple columns which can be sorted.

I tried with 100 plus columns and it works like a charm. I beleive you will not be doing a multi sort on more than this :)

[image: MultiSortedColumns 100 Plus]

Refer my plunker link with 500 columns grid

[MultiColumnSort](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bn2H4u171Dsi0Hk2xP5k?p=preview)

Comment: I had gone through the official docs and raised the question here since there are no limits specified.